# View responsible for top navbar in Odoo12

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

I'm trying to add a logo to the top navbar and I'm looking for the view id to inherit that will allow me to target propper elements with xpath.

[image]

I'm having trouble with locating the view responsible for the navbar layout that hold the two adjacent elements.

I have found something like this: `addons\website\views\website_navbar_templates.xml`. But it does not defines this two adjacent nodes (present inside browser inspect element tool):

```html
<ul class="o_menu_apps">
```

and

```html
<a class="o_menu_brand" role="button">
```

They are only present inside static xml: `addons\web\static\src\xml\menu.xml`. ​But I don't know if I can even modify this xml with my custom module and xpath.

Inside: `addons\website\views\website_templates.xml`
I saw this piece of code:

```xml
<template id="layout_logo_show" inherit_id="website.layout" customize_show="True" name="Show Logo">
    <xpath expr="//header//a[hasclass('navbar-brand')]" position="replace">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand logo">
            <span t-field="res_company.logo" t-options="{'widget': 'image'}" role="img" t-att-aria-label="'Logo of %s' % res_company.name" t-att-title="res_company.name" />
        </a>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Where does this logo goes? I don't see any logo in Odoo12. I think there is no class called 'navbar-brand'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overwriting the static xml file with my custom module like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates  xml:space="preserve">    
    <t t-extend="Menu">
        <t t-jquery="*" t-operation="replace">
            <div style="height:100%; background-color: #4c4c4c;">
                <nav class="o_main_navbar">
                    <ul class="o_menu_apps"/>
                    <div class="example_div">
                        <a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank">
                            <img src="example.png"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <a class="o_menu_brand" role="button"/>
                    <ul class="o_menu_sections" role="menu"/>
                    <ul class="o_menu_systray" role="menu"/>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>

</templates>
```

I placed this file inside `static/src/xml` and called it in manifest.py

```py
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/*.xml',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done dynamically as well. In this case we will use JavaScript code on the front-end and a controller to inform the front-end if a company logo exists for this company, then we use a get request from the front-end to get the company logo.

First we add img tag to to show the company logo from XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="Menu">
        <t t-jquery=".o_menu_apps" t-operation="prepend">
            <a id="company-logo-link" href="/web">
                <img id="company-logo" alt="Logo"/>
            </a>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

After that we add JavaScript to show the logo of the current user's company. We get the company ID from the current user's session.

```
odoo.define('web_company_logo.Menu', function (require) {
'use strict';

var session = require('web.session');
var Menu = require('web.Menu');

Menu.include({
    /**
    * @override
    */
    start: function (parent, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);

        // current url, <domain_name>:<port_number>
        var url = window.location.origin;

        // company id from the session
        var companyId = session.company_id;

        // use ajax to check if the company has a logo.
        // if there is no logo, remove the anchor, else
        // use the company's logo as the img src
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'company_id': companyId},
            url: `${url}/check_company_logo`,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Inside the success function');
                var result = JSON.parse(result);
                if (result.has_logo == true) {
                    $('#company-logo')[0].src = `${url}/web/image?model=res.company&id=${companyId}&field=logo`;
                }
                else {
                    $('#company-logo-link')[0].remove();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log('Error encountered');
            },
        });
    },
   });
});
```

For this JavaScript code to work the below controller should be added to inform the front-end if this company has a logo.

```
import json

from odoo import http
from odoo.http import request


class WebCompanyLogoController(http.Controller):

@http.route(['/check_company_logo'], type='http',
            auth="public", methods=['GET'],
            website=True, sitemap=False)
def check_company_logo(self, company_id=0):
    """
    Check if company has a logo
    :param company_id: ID of the company as an integer
    :return: bool
    """
    has_logo = bool(request.env['res.company'].browse(int(company_id)).logo)

    return json.dumps({
        'has_logo': has_logo,
    }, ensure_ascii=False)
```